# Best Hash Algorithm for Cache purposes?

Tags: algorithm, hash

I need to implement a cache mechanism for my server where I will read the contents (bytes) of static resources and provide the clients with a Hash of them. This way, I want to manually cache the files if the Hash didn't change (even after version updates).

I was investigating SHA, MD5, etc but these hashes are designed to be expensive. **I don't need a secure cryptographic hash**, I just need a **fast and deterministic** hash that has small collisions.

Any idea of a hash algorithm that fits this need?

Comment: Can these resource files change while the software is running?

Comment: it doesn't really matter, I have full control on this

Comment: How about something simple as CRC32? It should be reasonably fast. It's more of a checksum type thing though so I don't know how collision resistant it is.

Comment: Seems like the collision rate for CRC is too high, also I will be calculating this hash for big files, not sure if this affects

Comment: First off, this is already implemented in most HTTP servers and clients with their [caching mechanisms](https://web.dev/http-cache/). Secondly, how many files are we talking about? This will help determine the hash function output size needed, which is likely the most important consideration.

Comment: [Jenkins hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function) is easy to implement, fast, and provides a good distribution (i.e. low collision rate). I used it to great effect some years ago in a custom hash table implementation. The linked Wikipedia article gives a brief description, and links sources for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do want a secure hash.

Secure hashes are designed such that any 2 distinct files should have a distinct hash.  Collisions in MD5 and SHA1 are only produced by having 2 similar files, which are modified together to produce twins.

CRC by contrast is possible to compute simple changes in a file to come up with the any arbitrary CRC for a file, with only a few (4 or 8 I think) bytes being changed.

So a secure hash would allow you to see different files with almost 100% certainty.  When last asked this question (at work), I suggested CRC for a hash, and found that CRC32 was slower than MD5.

This was due to the fact that MD5 round did operations on a wider block of data than CRC32, and was effectively faster.

If you want guaranteed difference finding, use a secure hash.  Consider ignoring the broken hashes (MD5,MD4,MD3, MD2, SHA1, ...) as it could impact data integrity.  Actually test performance to see the throughput on your hardware, as some CPUs have help instructions to  speed HASH algorithms up.

Comment: You either need the security guarantees of a cryptographic hash or you don't. If you don't then the choice should be based on other requirements, including speed. All the deprecated secure hashes are perfectly adequate for non-security critical applications. They're also all too slow.